# how to add drop down in list menu in HTML web page

Tags: html, css

I have web page i want to add the drop down menu On Reference button i am using following code for css
I want like this website given template I am new to css please help

http://www.psdgraphics.com/templates/black-horizontal-html-and-css-dropdown-menu/

### This is the CSS File

```
   .menu {
float:right;
margin: 39px 18px 0 0;
height:47px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
   }



    .menu ul li {
list-style:none;
float:left;
    }



   menu.sub-menu {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
padding:10px;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
z-index: 598;
background: #353535 url(images/dropdown-list-bg.gif) repeat-x left top;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
 }

    .menu ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
display:block;
    }


    .menu .active {
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url();
    }

   .menu .stix {
width:2px;
font-size:0px;
background-image:url(image/seperator.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:0;
height:47px;
    }
```

below is my HTML code

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#page_one"><img src="image/overview_active.png" /></a></li>
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#page_two"><img src="image/strategy.gif"/></a></li>
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="image/draxxin.gif"/></a></li> 
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="image/excede.gif"/></a></li>
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="image/results.gif"/></a></li>
        <li class="stix"></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="image/reference.gif"/></a></li> 
        <li class="sub-menu">DRAXXIN</li>
        <li class="stix"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: my question i want like the given link dropdown for Referenc.gif List item

Comment: I still dont follow. What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that how to do like that dropdown in my menus when i click on any menu item it show  drop down menu

Comment: @user1357739 You need to be specific about the problem you're having. General "I need help" style questions get closed pretty quickly. Outline the exact problem you're having and what you've already tried.

Comment: @My code displays the Sub DRAXIN BEsided the Menue but i want that in dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navMenu">
    <ul style="height: 30px; width: 308px">
    <li id="wrapper1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 150px; height: 31px"><a style="color:black" href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
    <li id="wrapper3"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="wrapper4"><a style="color:black" href="#">Products</a>
    <ul>
    <li id="wrapper3"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navMenu{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#navMenu ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:30px;
}
#navMenu li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:#3A4956;
}
#navMenu ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px black solid;
}
#navMenu ul li a:hover{
    color:white;
}
#navMenu ul ul{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
} 
#navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    visibility:visible
}
#wrapper1{
    border-radius:8px 0 0 0;
    border-right:1px black solid

}
#wrapper4{
    border-radius:0 8px 0 0;
}
```